# Book recommendation on the human muscle system

Tags: muscles, book-recommendation

I would like to learn more about the exact mechanism behind our movements, especially about what happens during intense training when anaerobic state arises.

Comment: You can get reviews on those topics. What level of information do you expect?

Comment: @WYSIWYG I would like to dig really deep into this topic, so something around university level would be excellent, if that's what you meant by your second sentence, but I'm afraid, I didn't understand it.

Comment: You answered my second sentence. I think reviews would be also good.

Comment: `1.` Fundamentals of Anatomy & Physiology by Martini and Campbel Biology are quite useful. `2.` Have you seen this one? Muscle: Fundamental Biology and Mechanisms of Disease